# Some doubts w.r.t. short-circuit (||=) operator

Tags: ruby, operators

I noticed some interesting use of `||=` as below -

#### Code 1

```
array_1 ||= begin
    (1..5).to_a.map {|el| el*10}
end
puts array_1.to_s # [10,20,30,40,50]
```

So I executed its following modified version -

#### Code 2

```
array_2 ||= def some_method
    (1..5).to_a.map {|el| el*10}
end
puts array_2 # prints nothing
puts array_2.class # NilClass
puts some_method.to_s # [10,20,30,40,50]
```

1. Why does `array_2` gets initialised to `nil`?
2. Is it possible to invoke `some_method` using `array_2` object? how?

#### UPDATE

This is what I did for question 2

```
array_2 ||= "We've got #{def some_method;(1..5).to_a.map {|el| el*10};end;array_2.send(:some_method)}"
puts array_2 # We've got [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return value of a method definition expression (`def`) is implementation-defined. Most Ruby implementations simply return `nil` from a `def` expression, but Rubinius, for example, returns the compiled code of the method wrapped up in a `CompiledMethod` object.

Comment: Ok that answers `nil` assignment. And is there any way to initialize array_2 to `some_method's` return value without explicitly doing something like  `array_2 = some_method`

Answer (score 1):

When you declare any method it will simply return `nil` but when you call any method it will return the o/p of the last line return in that method unless you used return keyword.

Following should work for you

```
def some_method
    return (1..5).to_a.map {|el| el*10}
end

array_2 ||=some_method
```

Comment: I understand that. What I am looking for is some hack/one-liner that declares the method, invokes it and returns its output in a single shot?

Comment: `array_2 ||= some_method; def some_method;(1..5).to_a.map {|el| el*10};end`

Comment: this will give error because you're calling `some_method` before it has been defined

Comment: However I figured something similar `array_2 ||= "We've got #{def some_method;(1..5).to_a.map {|el| el*10};end;array_2.send(:some_method)}"`